# Div with contenteditable="true" - change innerHTML in DOMSubtreeModified event do infinitive loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `<div id="namingSchemes" contenteditable="true"></div>`

On this div I have event:

```
$('#namingSchemes').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", changeSchemaName);

function changeSchemaName(s) {      
    s.currentTarget.innerHTML = "<span>" + s.currentTarget.innerHTML + "</span>";
}
```

My problem appears when I try change innerHTML. It will again trigger my changeSchemaName and I have infinitive loop.

What I need is editable DIV and when text in this DIV is changed I will do some other adjustment for example wrap this text to SPAN.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wwd24tvj/) - here I add unbind to prevent infinitive loop but second time when I try to change value my event changeSchemaName is not triggered.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll have to figure out another way, changing the content of the element triggers the event, and it always will

Comment: What I need is that I will have editable div and if this div after "any" change event will be for example word "perfect" it will wrap it into span and this text I will have with different color for example red. Somethink like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788698/input-highlight-part-of-text/30789426?noredirect=1#comment49629236_30789426

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding `<span>` around the value, so why not ignore the change if it already starts with `<span>`, like this:

```
function changeSchemaName(s) {      
    if (s.currentTarget.innerHTML.indexOf("<span>") < 0 {
        s.currentTarget.innerHTML = "<span>" + s.currentTarget.innerHTML + "</span>";
    }
}
```

This way if there's already a `span` defined you won't keep setting it.

Or you can use `unbind` to remove the binding while your function does it's thing:

```
function changeSchemaName(s) {      
    $('#namingSchemes').unbind("DOMSubtreeModified", changeSchemaName);
    s.currentTarget.innerHTML = "<span>" + s.currentTarget.innerHTML + "</span>";
    $('#namingSchemes').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", changeSchemaName);
}
```

Comment: I would like to have editable div and if this div will contains some word for expample "perfect" it will wrap it with span and css will change color of this word. Somethink like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788698/input-highlight-part-of-text/